# ReSharper actions not working while editing individual file

Tags: asp.net, resharper, resharper-7.1

I've been asked to make some changes to an old ASP site, and I've been editing individual ASP files in VS (I don't have the original project file).  However, I'm finding that none of my favorite ReSharper actions (like [Selection Extend/Shrink](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#ExtendShrink_Selection)) are firing while editing that individual ASP file.  I know this feature [is supported](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/asp_net_editor.html) in ASP, and they work when I'm editing C# files as part of a larger project.

**Do these features only work when the ASP file is opened as part of an ASP.NET project?**  Is there something else incorrectly configured?

I'm using R# 7.1.3 C# Edition and VS 2012 Ultimate (11.0.61219.00).  Thanks!

#### Update 1

I just tested opening a C# file from VS without opening the C# Project file.  I was **NOT** able to use the ReSharper features.  Perhaps a project file truly is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper doesn't know anything about Classic ASP, which means there's a lot of functionality it just can't implement. For example, "extend selection" - extend to what? Because it doesn't know what the file format is, it has no way of knowing what code construct the selection should be extended to.

In a similar vein, it can't offer full functionality for known file types, such as C#, unless they're in a project, because the project gives it so much context. For example, all the types you're using are defined in assemblies that are referenced in the project, so without a project, you don't get the assemblies, you don't get any known types, so you don't get code completion.

Comment: Thanks @citizenmatt. That confirms what I thought. I'd still like the functionality the be available, but I can appreciate the requirement.